# How to remove command itself from output of a batch command executed using returnStdout flag true in Jenkinsfile (groovy)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cloudbees

I am using Jenkins Pipeline for my .net project. I dont want to use the default build number so I am trying to set the build number using the following commands in groovy.

```
def short_hash = bat(script: 'git log --pretty=format:\'%%h\' -n 1', returnStdout: true)
currentBuild.displayName = '0.0.' + "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}" +'.' + short_hash
```

What I am observing is that short_hash is having the value of batch command along with the result.

The jenkins documentation [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-bat-code-windows-batch-script) states that "script
Executes a Batch script. Multiple lines allowed. When using the returnStdout flag, you probably wish to prefix this with @, lest the command itself be included in the output."

I tried using @ but it is giving error while executing it. Any pointers?

Comment: Where are you adding the `@` char? Which error is coming up?

Comment: as the `@` is a `cmd` prefix for "don't echo the command line" and the command is `git`, it should be: `... script: '@git ...`

Comment: Thanks @Stephan, It worked. I was using @ before '.

Answer (score 2):

```
def short_hash = bat(script: '@git log --pretty=format:\'%%h\' -n 1', returnStdout: true)
currentBuild.displayName = '0.0.' + "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}" +'.' + short_hash
```

> put @ before git command